# How to fit a leaflet map under a bootsrap nav header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dictionary, leaflet

I'm using bootstrap in combination with a leaflet map. Now to give the map full height of the window I used `$("#map").height($(window).height());` But I have a nav header at the top of the page. This is the html of the bootstrap nav bar:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
  </nav>
```

This is my map div:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" id="map"></div>
```

Now when I load the page I get a scrollbar at the side because the map takes the full window height + the height of the nav bar. Is there a way to solve this? Can I add something to the css of the nav bar so the map will be behind it?

UPDATE:

After I implemented you'r suggestion @IvanSanchez, the map got real thin like this:
[image]

**UPDATE**

When I add the css with pixels like this it works and the thin map changes into a 600px height:

```
#map {
    display : table-cell;
    height : 800px;
    /*height: calc ( 100vh - 5em );*/
}
```

But I want it to be responsive so I need it in `%` or like @IvanSanchez suggested it.

Comment: Provide a code sample or JSfiddle to view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now to give the map full height of the window I used `$("#map").height($(window).height());`

Don't.

If you want to fit stuff to the viewport size, use the [`vh`, `vw`, `vmin` and `vmax` CSS units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units#Length_and_size).

If you cannot use absolutely positioned block elements to control the size of the map container, then use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) like `#map { height: calc ( 100vh - 5em ); }`

Comment: I tryed to do it as you suggested but than my map gets real thin (see picture I added in my question). When I change the height from `%` to `px` it does work but than I lose the dynamics of bootstrap..